# Spine.js, setting model default values

Tags: coffeescript, spine.js

There is in rails we have lifecycle hooks, which allows us doing this:

```
class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :record_signup

  private
    def record_signup
      self.signed_up_on = Date.today
    end
end
```

Is there best way to accomplish same thing (i need it to set some default values) in `Spine.js` ?

Currently i doing it this way, but maybe there is better way exists ?

```
class Subscription extends Spine.Model
    @record_signup: (self) ->
      self.signed_up_on = new Date()

Subscription.bind 'beforeSave', Subscription.record_signup
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CoffeeScript class bodies are executable :

```
class Subscription extends Spine.Model
    @record_signup: (self) ->
      self.signed_up_on = new Date()

    @bind 'beforeSave', @record_signup
```

Comment: which could be further simplified to: `@bind 'beforeSave', @record_signup` ?

Answer (score 1):

How about overriding the standard Model.create function to include your default values if they aren't set?

```
@create: (atts, options) ->
  atts.myVal or= 'someDefault'
  record = new @(atts)
  record.save(options)
```

Comment: This is look feasible, could we replace 2 bottom lines with single `super` line ?